# Подкиньте идею как решить

Tags: c#

нужна помощь с задачей. В задаче задано n чисел через пробел и нужно в ответ вывети количество переходов от чётных чисел к нечётным по порядку. Вот код:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // variable declaration
        var count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var string_input = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
        int[] int_input = new int[count];
        var output = 0;

        // string_input convert to int array
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            int_input[i] = int.Parse(string_input[i]);

        // check parity
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            if (int_input[i] % 2 == 0)
                output++;

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что когда вводиш несколько чётнвх или нечётних чисел подряд, то оно считает не правильно. Тобиж, при вводе например 4 чисел: 20 12 10 3 должно вывести 1, а выводит 3. (я знаю что у меня в коде проверка на чётность по тому оно и выводит 3, я просто не могу понять как мне сделать ето правильно). Очень интересно как же оно решаеться, помигите пожалуйста

Comment: отслеживайте четность переменных (сравнивайте с предыдущим значением), в случае если она меняется - увеличивайте счетчик

Comment: Так вы почему-то считаете не переходы, а количество чётных чисел

Answer (score 1):

Измените тут

```
    // check parity
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++)
        if (int_input[i] % 2 == 0 && int_input[i + 1] % 2 == 1)
            output++;
```

Comment: А если строка начнется не с четного значения?

Comment: @azlov А что собственно должно быть если с нечетного? 3 2 3 => 1

Comment: да, не заметил, что по условию считаем переходы от четных к нечетным (думал все). Извини)